# Getting the string in the middle of two other strings in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I need to find the string in between two other strings. How could I do this?

```
string = "vHELLOv"
```

Finding `"HELLO"` which is in between of two lowercase `"v"`'s

Another example could be:

```
string = "/World/"
```

Finding `"World"` in the middle of the two `"/"`s

Comment: I suggest to look at regexes ([`re`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html) module)

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: In case there is just one character arround: `"vHELLOv"[1:-1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Use `regex` (regular expression) library for pattern matching.

```py
import re

# 1st pattern: vHELLOv
re.findall(r"v(.*?)v", "vHELLOv")


# 2nd pattern: /HELLO/
re.findall(r"/(.*?)/", "/HELLO/")

## NOTE: For regex in python you do not have to escape / with a \. 
#        But, if you want to use a similar regex universally elsewhere, 
#        consider escaping each / with a \.
#
#        Example: r"/(.*?)/" ==> r"\/(.*?)\/"
```

EDIT: Added lazy quantifier `.*?` instead of `.*` inside the `()` as suggested by [Jan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231450/jan).

- pattern: `r"v(.*)v"` **Greedy** --> [Example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YRR7bR/1)
- pattern: `r"v(.*?)v"` **Lazy** --> [Example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/YRR7bR/2) <kbd>BETTER</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about two identical strings surrounding another, you can use the split method:

```
string = "vHELLOv"
surrounder = "v"
x = string.split(surrounder)

print(x[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove punctuation, you could use the following regex expression in Python:

```
import re
s = "/World/"
new_s = re.sub(r'\W', "", s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in various ways as

```
 import re

 text = "vHELLOv" #or txt = "/World/"
 re.match(r"(v|\/)(\w*)(v|\/)", text).group(2)
 or
 re.search(r"(v|\/)(\w*)(v|\/)", text).group(2)
```

This is the regex methods
You can do it also with string replace as

```
txt.replace(txt[0], "") if txt[0] == txt[-1] else txt
```

Answer (score 0):

*"Another example could be"* - Just those words made me think you are not only interested in `v` or `/` but **any** type of character that surrounds a string of interest. Therefor you could try a pattern like:

```
^(.)(.+)\1$
```

Or if you want to define the possibilities:

```
^([\/v])(.+)\1$
```

This way you would capture the first character in a capture group that you can refer to later down the line. You don't need to distinquish between `v` or `/` or any character perse. Now grab group 2 from a search result, e.g.:

```
import re
s = 'vHELLOv'
print(re.search(r'^(.)(.+)\1$', s).group(2))
```

returns:

```
HELLO
```